# Connecting subdomain to tomcat7 war instance with Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, tomcat

I need to connect a war instance (war-demo.war) with `clojure2.msms.com` using Nginx webserver on Ubuntu.

This is what I've done.

### 1. Setting nginx/tomcat

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, I setup so that `tomcat.msms.com` is connected to tomcat7. Tomcat7 is installed with `apt-get` (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get). I also checked `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` is correctly installed.

```
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream tomcat {
        server 127.0.0.1:8008;
        keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name tomcat.msms.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_tomcat.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error_tomcat.log;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /excluded {
            return 403;
        } 
}
```

### 2. war file setup

I uploaded the war file in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` so that `tomcat.msms.com/war-demo` shows correct results.

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps> ls
ROOT  war-demo.war
```

### 3. Connecting `clojure2.msms.com` to the `war-demo.war`.

I created a CNAME `clojure2.msms.com` and added this configuration file in the `ubuntu` directory of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

```
server {
    listen  80; 
    server_name clojure2.msms.com;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8008/;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Then I modified `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`

```
 146 │       <Host name="clojure2.msms.com" appBase="webapps"                                                         
 147 │           unpackWARS="true" autoDeploy="true">                                                                  
 148 │         <Context path="" docBase="war-demo" debug="0" privileged="true" />                                      
 149 │         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"                           
 150 │                prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"                                                     
 151 │                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />                               
 152 │       </Host>
```

I restarted tomcat server with `sudo service tomcat7 restart`, and 
I seem to have the `clojure2.msms.com` well installed from the manager.

[image]

But the `clojure2.msms.com` link shows the default tomcat7 server, not the `war-demo.war` instance. What is wrong in my configurations?

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solutions.

### Create another service

```
  <Service name="Clojure">
    <Connector port="8007" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8442" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="clojure2">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="clojure2" appBase="webapps2" 
          unpackWARS="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

The base directory is webapps2 and it uses a new port 8007.

### Make clojure2.conf use any other port.

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, create a new `nginx` service.

```
server {
    listen  80; 
    server_name clojure2.msms.com;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8007/;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

### Copy the war file into the webapps2 directory

Copy the war file into the `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps2` directory. Don't forget to change the war file name as ROOT.war.

### Restart the tomcat

```
tomcat7> sudo service tomcat7 restart
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ] 
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ]
```

There might be a better solution than this, but this solution just works as I expected.